# Android Wear OS App with Tiles and Complications

Tags: android, watch, tile

even thought I have 25 years experience with multiple backend dev languages, I'm brand new to Android and Wear OS. I'm finding it difficult to understand how to build a simple Tile and/or Complication.

My ask is simple, I have an API that returns 1 number, I want that number to show in a Title and in a Complication on my watch.

I've been toying around with Android Studio and analyzing some examples online.

my first question is, do I need to build an Android OS app first and then add the Tile and Complication services to the app? or can I just build an Android Wear OS app directly?

I had some issues testing the tile/complication without going thru the "Watch" app to select the titles and add the complication to my watch faces. Had no idea on how to tie the two together.

I just need a little guidance on what steps to perform to properly develop the app and test it using the emulators.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sort the issue, but going to the run configuration and selecting the tile service i want to run. this allowed me to have the tile running and was able to debug. Thanks